# caption disappear when I use \begin {figure}[H]

Tags: latex

I found my caption disappear when I use the [H]

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=13.5cm,height=9.5cm]{abc1.pdf}
\caption{abcd}
\end{center}
\label{fig:abcd}    
\end{figure}
```

I found my caption appear when I use [ht]
How solve this when I still want use [H]?
Thanks

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]. Are you loading the `float` package? Unrelated to your problem, but don't use the `center` environment in a float, this will add superfluous vertical spacing - use `\centering` instead. Also don't specify both the width and height of the image, this will distort the aspect ratio. You also don't need the file suffix `.pdf`, latex will automatically choose the file format best suited for the engine you use for compilation.

Comment: Last but not least: check if you really, really, really must use the `H` option. This will most certainly lead to suboptimal placement of the float. Use `htbp` and let latex do what it can do best and place the floats for you. The result will be much better.